# Trying to set the size of a span as a percentage of size of contents

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I think I've got what sounds like a simple request but is probably actually stupid hard to do, but I haven't worked in HTML in a long time.

First, I only have to support IE.  I understand WebKit is often, but until there's a WebKit browser built into Windows Phone 7, I'm limited to IE.

I've got a piece of text that I want to animate in and out horizontally.  I really don't want to measure it ahead of time for internationalization reasons.  What I'd love to do is be able to set something like this:

```
<span id="parent" style="width: 50% of child's size">
  <span id="child">Hello, cruel world</span>
</span>
```

And have it look like

```
Hello, cru
```

Any way to accomplish this?

Comment: You realize that the `span` has *no* child?

Comment: Isn't the text "Hello, cruel world" a child of it?

Comment: No, the text inside is just text. Child, parent, sibling, etc reference the nodes in the HTML, not the text. For example, in JS if you did element.child of that span you'd return 0.

Comment: edited to create a child span around the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Span has no child as David said, also, all you have to do is set span to a block (`display:block`) and 50% and it'll take the width of 50% of the parent (if thats what you mean) and then do `overflow:hidden` which will snip it off at 50% and wont show the rest of whats inside.

-- UPDATE 2 --

Here is the raw JS. Let me know if you have any questions. This does the same thing as i had in jQuery, but with just JS. plop it in a script tag and you should be good to go.

```
//Setting up vars
$ = document;
$parent = $.getElementById('parent');
$child = $.getElementById('child');

//Set the styles for the child
$child.style.width = $child.offsetWidth+'px'
$child.style.display = 'block';

//Set the styles for the parent
$parent.style.width = ($child.offsetWidth*0.5)+'px'
$parent.style.overflow = 'hidden';
$parent.style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: I'm looking for almost the opposite of that.  I want it to take 50% of the width of the child [whatever you want to call it]

Comment: You'd need to use JS, but what you're calling the child == the width OF that element. (tiniest way to give an example is with jQuery so...) basically you'd do `$(this).css({width:($(this).width()/0.5)+'px'})`. Then, if you set it (in the CSS) to display:block; and overflow:hidden itll hide it.

Comment: so in the edited example above?  what would I do if I want the "parent" span to be 50% of the width of the "child" span's effective width?

Comment: added an example above with a lot of comments. Hope it helps! Also, because this is JS/jQuery this wont run until AFTER the page loads, so you dont have to worry about calculating it beforehand as you said.

Comment: It looks like it's right, but I don't know jQuery.  Would you mind terribly doing the translation?

Comment: OK, updated my code, let me know if it works. It should, i tested it with your HTML and it's working for me. If it works, don't forget to mark it as answered ;)